# Change in for-loop range by deleting a list element

Tags: python, string, for-loop, string-length, del

I am new to python and programming in general and currently learning the fundamentals. In the script below I am trying to check the number of letters in each list element and delete ones with five and more letters. I am using for-loop to achieve this but an issue is occurring because of the change in the number of list elements which does not corresponds to the for-loop range considered initially. I tried to let the range vary itself but I errors are still obtained.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

magicians =['alice','david','carolina']

def counter(word):
    x= sum (c != ' ' for c in word)
    return x

print magicians
for i in range (0,3):
        magicians[i]=magicians[i].title()
print magicians
q=
Y=range (0,q)

for i in Y:
    x= counter(magicians[i])
    print x    
    if x<=5:
        print 'this component will be deleted:', magicians[i]
        del magicians[i]
        q=q-1
        Y=range (0,q)
print magicians
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that the `Y = ...` within the loop does *not* have an effect on the `Y` in `for i in Y`.

```
for i in Y:
    ...
        Y=range (0,q)
```

You *could* change your code to use a `while` loop, and manage the current index and the maximum index manually, but this is very prone to error:

```
i = 0
while i < q:
    x= counter(magicians[i])
    if x<=5:
        print 'this component will be deleted:', magicians[i]
        del magicians[i]
        q=q-1
    else:
        i += 1
```

Instead of deleting elements from a list while iterating the same list, it is much better practice to populate a *second* list, holding only the elements you want to keep, e.g. using a list comprehension:

```
good_magicians = [m for m in magicians if counter(m) > 5]
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a sophisticated answer to your problem in this post: [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

The easiest one is to create a new list only containing the elements you actually want.

Comment: Why was my answer voted down? Please explain your reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually voted up but (-1) is what appeared.